# How to pass a SESSION value from a drop down box in html

Tags: php, html, session

I have a drop down value code that contains a list of items, I wanted to post the value that I've selected into another page called `checkout.php`

here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_POST['submit'])
    $_SESSION['movies'] = $_POST['movie'];
?>

<form name="booking" action="checkout.php" onsubmit="return validateBooking()" method="post" target="_blank">
    <p class="selection"> Movies</p></br>
    <select name="movie">
        <option value="empty">Please Select a Movie</option>
        <option value="AC">Dunkirk</option>
        <option value="RC">Annabelle</option>
        <option value="CH">The Dark Tower</option>
        <option value="AF">Logan Lucky</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: What happens when you execute it?

Comment: Where's the code that you tried something with and what does this method do? `validateBooking()`.

Comment: Where is the submit button for your form?

Comment: Here is the submit button

 <input id= "submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" name = "submit">
   </form>

Answer (score 0):

use like this, first give `action=""` so form will be posted on the current page, then store the data in session and redirect to `checkout.php`. Now at checkout pge you can get the data from session

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_POST['movie']){
        $_SESSION['movies'] = $_POST['movie'];
        header('Location: checkout.php');
    }
     ?>

    <form name="booking" action="" onsubmit="return validateBooking()" method="post">
        <p class="selection"> Movies </p></br>
        <select name="movie">
            <option value="empty">Please Select a Movie</option>
            <option value="AC">Dunkirk</option>
            <option value="RC">Annabelle</option>
            <option value="CH">The Dark Tower</option>
            <option value="AF">Logan Lucky</option>
        </select>
   </form>
```

you can write the same php code on `checkout.php` when you give `action='checkout.php'` as

```
<form name="booking" action="checkout.php" onsubmit="return validateBooking()" method="post">
```

**checkout.php** contains

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_POST['movie']){
        $_SESSION['movies'] = $_POST['movie'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: what do mean by writing the same php code oncheckout.php ?

Comment: I mean posting the form on this page and keeping data in session, we can directly post data on checkout.pbp